# Exchange the order of only the middle letters of a word and keep the order of the punctuation mark if there is one

Tags: r, string, list

I require a function that exchanges only the characters of the middle of the word (between first and last character). The function should not change anything if the word is composed of less than 4 characters. The function has an argument called `exclude` which is a vector of potential punctuation marks at the end of a word.

You can assume that there is only one possible punctuation mark. If there is such a mark, it should not be changed and not counted towards the number of characters the actual word is composed of.

My idea is to

- exclude any punctuation mark
- take out the first letter of the word
- take out the last letter of the word
- exchange the remaining letters
- add back the first and last letters and punctuation marks

---

```
string <-c("well!")
interchange.middle.of.word <- function(string, exclude = c(",",".","!","?")){
  result1 <- strsplit(string, split= "")
  result2 <- unlist(result1)
  result3 <- result2[ - which(result2 %in% exclude)]
  result4 <- head(result3,-1)
  result5 <- tail(result4,-1)
  result6 <- sample(result5,replace = FALSE)
  result7 <- c(result3[1],result6)
  result8 <- c(result7, result4[length(result4)])
  result9 <- c(result8, result2[which(result2 %in% exclude)])
  result10 <- paste(result9,collapse="")
  return(result10)
}
```

The code worked for the example `'well!'`, but not for another example like `'hello?'` or words less than 3 letters like `'Tes'`:

- for `'hello?'` my result was `'hlell?'`
- for `'Tes'` my result was `'NA'`

I would be grateful if anyone can tell me where I went wrong about the code.
Many thanks.

Comment: You have used the word "exchange" to describe the requirement, but in your code you are calling `sample()` which *randomizes* the order of the middle characters. My instinctive interpretation of the word "exchange" is that you meant *reversing* the order of the middle characters. Can you clarify whether you want to *reverse* or *randomize* the middle characters?

Comment: thank you for your comment. the requirement is to randomly change the order of the letters in the middle. For example for "well!" the result should be two: "well!", and "wlel!"

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to *reverse* the order of the middle characters:

```
revmiddle <- function(s,exclude=c(',','.','!','?')) {
    if (nchar(s)<4L) return(s);
    x <- strsplit(s,'')[[1L]];
    if (x[length(x)]%in%exclude) {
        punc <- x[length(x)];
        x <- x[-length(x)];
    } else {
        punc <- NULL;
    }; ## end if
    paste(collapse='',c(x[1L],x[seq(length(x)-1L,2L)],x[length(x)],punc));
}; ## end revmiddle()
```

Demo:

```
revmiddle('well!');
## [1] "wlel!"
revmiddle('hello?');
## [1] "hlleo?"
revmiddle('Tes');
## [1] "Tes"
```

---

To *randomize* the order of the middle characters:

```
randmiddle <- function(s,exclude=c(',','.','!','?')) {
    if (nchar(s)<4L) return(s);
    x <- strsplit(s,'')[[1L]];
    if (x[length(x)]%in%exclude) {
        punc <- x[length(x)];
        x <- x[-length(x)];
    } else {
        punc <- NULL;
    }; ## end if
    paste(collapse='',c(x[1L],sample(x[-c(1L,length(x))]),x[length(x)],punc));
}; ## end randmiddle()
```

Demo (intentionally performing many executions and collecting sorted unique results, which effectively demonstrates all possible outcomes):

```
sort(unique(replicate(1e3L,randmiddle('well!'))));
## [1] "well!" "wlel!"
sort(unique(replicate(1e3L,randmiddle('hello?'))));
## [1] "hello?" "hlelo?" "hlleo?"
sort(unique(replicate(1e3L,randmiddle('Tes'))));
## [1] "Tes"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your code is far more precise and efficient than mine. One very small thing though is that the requirement is to exchange the order randomly not reverse...but still very helpful!

Comment: @LoveVegas You're welcome! See edit for randomization implementation. Your use of `sample()` was correct.